# Counting the occurrences of similar rows of data frame

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(CSF = c(10,10,13,11,13,10), CSF.1 = c(11,11,13,12,13,11), D13 = c(10,9,11,11,11,10), D13.1 = c(13,10,12,11,12,13))


data
                CSF     CSF.1   D13      D13.1
100000_BA_M     10       11      10        13
100000_BA_F     10       11       9        10
100001_BA_M     13       13      11        12
100001_BA_F     11       12      11        11
100002_BA_M     13       13      11        12
100002_BA_F     10       11      10        13
```

How do I get the counts of rows in this data frame with the same values for all columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by:

```
library(plyr)
count(data)
```